# Having Problem with Android Build In Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am trying to Build for Android in unity and face a Duplicate Class error.

Current gradle : 6.1.1

[image: Packages]

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in the following modules: androidx.annotation.annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.3.0.jar), androidx.annotation.annotation-1.3.0.jar (annotation-1.3.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (annotation-1.1.0.jar)
  Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in the following modules: androidx.annotation.annotation-1.3.0.jar (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.3.0.jar), androidx.annotation.annotation-1.3.0.jar (annotation-1.3.0.jar) and annotation-1.1.0.jar (annotation-1.1.0.jar)
```

I tried Differt Gradle and JDK but still the same problem

Comment: Solved it By Deleting Plugins Folder and Unity Creates it again with Proper Classes